# db2 "describes" console table output is unreadable

Tags: bash, console, formatting, db2, db2-luw

I don't know how to call this "messy console output" so I can't google for a solution.

[image: screenshot of terminal]

I run `db2 describe indexes for table TABLENAME show detail`

How I'm able to read the output of this command in a human readable format?

Comment: I'd suggest updating the question with what exactly you want to parse out of this output; once you know what you want to derive from the output, a couple ideas come to mind ... 1) redirect all output to a file and then parse the file with your favorite commands (eg, awk, grep, sed, cut, etc) ... 2) redirect all output to a pipe and parse the piped results with your favorite commands (eg, awk, grep, sed, cut, etc) ... 3) see if `db2` has any options that can reduce/reformat some of the output for you (though you'll likely still need to implement option #1 or #2

Answer (score 2):

You may put the following into a file and run it from the Db2 CLP:

> $ db2 -f myfile.sql

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

BEGIN
  DECLARE L_INDSCHEMA VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE L_INDNAME   VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE L_UNIQUE    VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE L_COLCOUNT  SMALLINT;
  DECLARE L_IDXTYPE   CHAR(26);
  DECLARE L_IDXPART   CHAR(18);
  DECLARE L_IDXID     SMALLINT;
  DECLARE L_DATATYPE  VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE L_HASHED    CHAR(1);
  DECLARE L_LENGTH    SMALLINT;
  DECLARE L_PATTERN   VARCHAR(500);
  DECLARE L_COLNAMES  VARCHAR(1984);

  DECLARE SQLSTATE    CHAR(5);
  DECLARE l1 RESULT_SET_LOCATOR VARYING;

  CALL ADMIN_CMD('DESCRIBE INDEXES FOR TABLE SYSIBM.SYSTABLES SHOW DETAIL');
  ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATOR (l1) WITH PROCEDURE ADMIN_CMD;
  ALLOCATE C1 CURSOR FOR RESULT SET l1;
  L1: LOOP
    FETCH C1 INTO 
        L_INDSCHEMA, L_INDNAME, L_UNIQUE, L_COLCOUNT, L_IDXTYPE, L_IDXPART
      , L_IDXID, L_DATATYPE, L_HASHED, L_LENGTH, L_PATTERN, L_COLNAMES
    ;
    IF SQLSTATE = '02000' THEN LEAVE L1; END IF;
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x'0a' || RTRIM(L_INDSCHEMA) || '.' || L_INDNAME );
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  UNIQUE RULE : ' || L_UNIQUE);
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  COLUMN COUNT: ' || L_COLCOUNT);
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  INDEX TYPE  : ' || L_IDXTYPE);
    --CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  INDEX PART  : ' || L_IDXPART);
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  IID         : ' || L_IDXID);
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  COLUMN NAMES: ' || L_COLNAMES);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
END
@
```

Answer (score 1):

These are just long lines wrapped around to the width of your console. You could pipe the command output to vim or other editor to avoid wrapping:

```
db2 describe indexes for table TABLENAME | vim
```

There isn't a way to tell the DB2 command line processor to output data in a different format.

Comment: You asked what exactly I want to do with the output, I just want to read it myself.
I feel like the first things you see on my screenshot (index Number of...) are a table header because due to the docs that's exactly what the command should return.

So as you suggested I played around with pipe and vim (and with nano, atom), and yes it looks differently, but still it seems to not have the format it expected to have so I'm able to read it.

Do you have any other tips?

Comment: Pipe to `less -S`, and then you can use the arrow keys to scroll right (and left) to see all of the output without line wrapping.